# inject $http into directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to inject $http into directive controller like the following :

**JS**

```
app.direcitve('customDirecitve',function(){
     return : 'E',
     scope : {
         url : "@",
         urlParams : "@"
     } ,
     controller  : ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude,$http) { 
         $http.post($scope.url,$scope.urlParams).success(function (data) {  

         });
    ]};        
});
```

what is wrong with this injection ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to respect the same order for your injections :

```
controller  : ['$scope','$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', '$http',  function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $http) { 
         $http.post($scope.url,$scope.urlParams).success(function (data) {  

         });
```